# Exporting RCP as a product

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am deploying my eclipse rcp product into some folder say C:\deploy\eclipse.
But 
Here i am facing a problem,while i was exporting to the same location it says export failed,
[image]

Since my project is in development stage each time i do changes in the code,i need to deploy to perform unit testing its pretty time consuming.All that i want to achieve is just override the same deployed location, i don't know if it is possible? The current approach was just go and delete the currently deployed folder and then export again, this is odd i guess, can someone drive me in a better approach

Comment: Click that "Details>>" button, and see what the error is.

Comment: yes i knew that there was a dependency problem with the version ,how to overcome that, what is the best practice to override the previous deployed location

Comment: You should always deploy into a new or an empty directory, otherwise the previous deployment can conflict with the new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to setup a **headless build** which means that you're able to trigger a build of your RCP application from the commandline. Once you've established a headless build you can write some sort of **batch file** which for example cleans up the deployment directory before the build.
You can integrate this batch file in your Eclipse IDE via **External Tools**.
Here is a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePDEBuild/article.html) on how to setup a headless build.